# Expandable list View deleting from sqlite database using a Button

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an Expandable List View which has a Delete button which is supossed to delete from the adapter first then from the DATABASE. The code runs fine on an emulator Problem is when i hit the Delete button it only deletes the last item on the list always. No matter which button i clicked. i want it to delete the respective group item of the button which i click. Could someone tell me which is the right rowId to use in order to delete the specific group item from the DB? Here's my code for the Button click listener

```
 @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
}

TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

Button delButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delButton);
delButton.setFocusable(false); // remove focus from the button
delButton.setOnClickListener( // del onclick listener
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String[] columns = new String[] { testshop.TABLE_ROW_ID,
                        testshop.TABLE_ROW_ONE, testshop.TABLE_ROW_TWO };
                Cursor cursor = testshop.db.query(testshop.TABLE_NAME, columns, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();// move the cursor to the first item
                if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    do{
                      Long rowId = cursor.getLong(0);
                    String item_name = cursor.getString(1);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());}

                }
                                       //delete from group array elements
                _listDataHeader.remove(item_name);

                notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify of data change in array
                testshop.deleteRow(testshop.TABLE_NAME,
                        testshop.TABLE_ROW_ID, Long.toString(rowId)); //delete from database 

                //I'm using this toast to debug
                Toast.makeText(_context, "Sucessfully Deleted" +rowId + getdeletedString(rowId),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
```

Comment: You are supposed to remember the IDs when you are loading the data from the DB, and store them in the adapter. Consider using a [SimpleCursorTreeAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html).

Comment: How Would I do that? The problem is Associating each button on the list with a particular item on the list. Deleting it from DB Works only that i delete the wrong item @CL.

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you do not understand about the  `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` examples and tutorials?

Comment: Yeah. How I'm going to link the button and the the listview item so as to be able to delete it from the DB in the Adapter class @CL.